# What is the difference between await and ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, configureawait

Let's say I got an `async` method in C# .Net Core:

```
public Task<ResultClass> Action() { ... }
```

What is the difference between invoking: `ResultClass res = await Action();`

and invoking: `ResultClass res = Action().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: `GetResult()` blocks the thread until the `Task` completes **which is a very bad thing**. You should never use `GetResult()`.

Comment: Do you mean it won't even return to the context of the caller? And is it the same as a regular sync call?

Answer (score 3):

The *await* keyword will free the current thread during the work. So if you have a limited number of thread it's really useful.

The "GetAwaiter().GetResult()" will do the same but synchronously so the current thread will be blocked during the work.

The "ConfigureAwait(false)" is a configuration that have no sense if you are in synchronous code but can be usefull with the *await*

```
await Action().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That you ensure the following will be called directly and avoid potential dead locks.

Comment: "The `GetAwaiter().GetResult()"` will do the same" - no, it does not "do the same but synchronously" thing as `await`: the thread calling `GetResult()` does not yield itself to the thread-pool: the thread is blocked instead.

Comment: I meant "the same work" and the second part of the sentence explains the differences.

Comment: But it doesn't do "the same work" - it's _fundamentally different_.

Comment: I should maybe have specified "the same functional work" ? :p

Comment: The only similarity between `await` and `GetResult()` is that *if nothing bad happens **and** the Task succeeds* - or if the Task is already completed - then the caller will have the `Task`'s `.Result` value - but that's it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when using GetResult(), the task will run on the same thread like a regular sync method, while with await, it will run on a different thread which will return to the thread pool at the end?

Comment: @Dai I think we a just not align about the term. By "Work" I mean what the method is supposed to do. By example a database call. In both case the database call (the work) will be done and the result will be the same. But the mechanism  to acheive that work is obviously totally different under the hood.

Comment: @YonatanNir The freed thread will come back into the thread pool if you use one. By example that's why it's important in ASP.NET to use "await" because you have a limited number of thread.

Comment: @Arcord that's with await. And with GetResult, what will happen? Will it run a new thread? and if it does, what happens to it in the end?

Comment: With the GetResult the same thread still used. Meaning it will be blocked during the whole operation (network call, file system IO, ...).